# Matlab mex memory handling - same input different result

Tags: c, matlab, memory, mex

I ve converted a computationally expensive part of my Matlab code into a C mex file, which greatly speeded up the calculation. The problem is that in some runs the C mex code gives exactly the same result as the Matlab code (within the machine accuracy), whereas in some others there is a significant discrepancy between the two (reaching even 1e-3). Furthermore, there are times that the C mex code disagrees with itself by giving in consecutive runs different results with exactly the same inputs. I guess that the problem is probably caused by some incorrect memory handling due to my programming. This is highly likely as thats my first attempt to create a C mex file.

I attach my mexFunction which calls another C function (in the same file) to perform the calculations. I would be grateful if you could give me some insight on my problem. Please let me know if you need any other part of the code.

Thanks in advance,

Panos

```
void BladeElementGC(const mwIndex InterestBE, const mwIndex BladeElement,
        const double *WakeXYZ, const double *RQuarter, const double *BE_RControl, const double *BE_Gamma,
        const mwSize NoOfBlades, const mwSize NoOfFilaments, const mwSize NoOfSegments, const mwSize NoOfWakeItems,
        const mwSize NoOfElements,
        const double conf_CompressibleBiot, const double conf_M, const double conf_CompressibleWakeMachMax,
        const double conf_VortexCoreOffset,
        const double conf_VortexDelta,
        const double conf_kin_visc,
        const double conf_VatistasN,
        const double conf_BoundVorticity,
        double *GCBladeElement)
{

    mwIndex Filament;
    double Temp1[3], Temp2[3], Temp3[3];

    GCBladeElement[0] = 0.;
    GCBladeElement[1] = 0.;
    GCBladeElement[2] = 0.;

    Filament = BladeElement;


    TrailingFilamentGC(InterestBE, Filament,
        WakeXYZ, BE_RControl, BE_Gamma,
        NoOfBlades, NoOfFilaments, NoOfSegments, NoOfWakeItems,
        NoOfElements,
        conf_CompressibleBiot, conf_M, conf_CompressibleWakeMachMax,
        conf_VortexCoreOffset,
        conf_VortexDelta,
        conf_kin_visc,
        conf_VatistasN,
        Temp1);


    TrailingFilamentGC(InterestBE, Filament+1,
        WakeXYZ, BE_RControl, BE_Gamma,
        NoOfBlades, NoOfFilaments, NoOfSegments, NoOfWakeItems,
        NoOfElements,
        conf_CompressibleBiot, conf_M, conf_CompressibleWakeMachMax,
        conf_VortexCoreOffset,
        conf_VortexDelta,
        conf_kin_visc,
        conf_VatistasN,
        Temp2);

    if (conf_BoundVorticity>0)
    {

        BoundElementGC(InterestBE, BladeElement,
        WakeXYZ, RQuarter, BE_RControl, BE_Gamma,
        NoOfBlades, NoOfFilaments, NoOfSegments, NoOfWakeItems,
        NoOfElements,
        conf_CompressibleBiot, conf_M, conf_CompressibleWakeMachMax,
        conf_VortexCoreOffset,
        conf_VortexDelta,
        conf_kin_visc,
        conf_VatistasN,
        Temp3);

    }
    else
    {
        Temp3[0] = 0.;
        Temp3[1] = 0.;
        Temp3[2] = 0.;
    }


    GCBladeElement[0] = Temp2[0] - Temp1[0] + Temp3[0];
    GCBladeElement[1] = Temp2[1] - Temp1[1] + Temp3[1];
    GCBladeElement[2] = Temp2[2] - Temp1[2] + Temp3[2];



}




/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    mwIndex InterestBE;
    mwIndex BladeElement;
    double *WakeXYZ;
    double *RQuarter;
    double *BE_RControl;
    double *BE_Gamma;
    double *GCBladeElement;

    const mwSize *dimsWakeXYZ;
    const mwSize *dimsBE_RControl;

    mwSize NoOfBlades, NoOfFilaments, NoOfSegments, NoOfWakeItems;
    mwSize NoOfElements, NoOfDimensions;

    double p_CompressibleBiot;
    double *p_M;
    double *p_CompressibleWakeMachMax;
    mwSize p_WakePointsNo;
    double p_BoundVorticity;

    double *p_VortexCoreOffset;
    double *p_VortexDelta;
    double *p_kin_visc;
    double *p_VatistasN;


    //----------------------------------------------------------
    // First retrieve inputs
    //----------------------------------------------------------

    /* Get the value of the scalar input InterestBE  */
    InterestBE = (mwIndex)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

    /* Get the value of the scalar input Filament  */
    BladeElement = (mwIndex)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);

    /* create a pointer to the real data in the WakeXYZ matrix  */
    WakeXYZ = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);

    /* create a pointer to the real data in the RQuarter matrix  */
    RQuarter = mxGetPr(prhs[3]);

    /* create a pointer to the real data in the BE_RControl matrix  */
    BE_RControl = mxGetPr(prhs[4]);

    /* create a pointer to the real data in the BE_RControl matrix  */
    BE_Gamma = mxGetPr(prhs[5]);


    /* create pointers to the fields of the conf structure  */

    p_CompressibleBiot = mxGetScalar(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "CompressibleBiot"));
    p_M = mxGetPr(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "M"));
    p_CompressibleWakeMachMax = mxGetPr(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "CompressibleWakeMachMax"));
    p_VortexCoreOffset = mxGetPr(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "VortexCoreOffset"));
    p_VortexDelta = mxGetPr(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "VortexDelta"));
    p_kin_visc = mxGetPr(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "kin_visc"));
    p_VatistasN = mxGetPr(mxGetField(prhs[6], 0, "VatistasN"));
    p_WakePointsNo = (mwSize)mxGetScalar(mxGetField(prhs[6],0,"WakePoints"));
    p_BoundVorticity = mxGetScalar(mxGetField(prhs[6],0,"BoundVorticity"));

    // Get the dimensions of the WakeXYZ array
    dimsWakeXYZ = mxGetDimensions(prhs[2]);

    // Get the dimensions of the BE_RControl array
    dimsBE_RControl = mxGetDimensions(prhs[4]);

    NoOfBlades = dimsWakeXYZ[0];
    NoOfFilaments = dimsWakeXYZ[1];
    NoOfSegments = dimsWakeXYZ[2];
    NoOfWakeItems = dimsWakeXYZ[3];
    NoOfElements = dimsBE_RControl[1];

    //----------------------------------------------------------
    // Call the calculation subroutine
    //----------------------------------------------------------

    /* create the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,3,mxREAL);
    GCBladeElement = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    BladeElementGC(InterestBE, BladeElement,
            WakeXYZ, RQuarter, BE_RControl, BE_Gamma,
            NoOfBlades, NoOfFilaments, NoOfSegments, NoOfWakeItems,
            NoOfElements,
            p_CompressibleBiot, *p_M, *p_CompressibleWakeMachMax,
            *p_VortexCoreOffset,
            *p_VortexDelta,
            *p_kin_visc,
            *p_VatistasN,
            p_BoundVorticity,
            GCBladeElement);

 }
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in the code. I usually explicitly cast everything after using `mxGetPr`, so try doing that. How does BladeElementGC assign GCBladeElement? Finally, inside BladeElementGC can you print all the input variables and check if they're getting passed correctly all the time?

Comment: Dear Ansari, thanks for your help. I have tried the explicit casting and nothing has changed. I have tried printing the input data of BladeElementGC and everything looks fine (for the test cases I ve tried). I have added in my message above the BladeElementGC subroutine for your reference. Please let me know if you require anything further and thanks again.

Comment: I 've done an extensive testing by printing different variables and comparing between Matlab and C and discovered a series of very subtle bugs, which didn't cause problems when using only Matlab, but created trouble when combining Matlab and C. Problem almost solved and thanks a lot for your time!